# PhoneGap Build app on Android just hangs (Phonegap Build .apk Samsung Note)

Tags: android, cordova, ripple

Hey I've downloaded my apk file from Phonegap Build and my app just hangs there when I start it up after installation (via qrcode download). There is a white screen with a loading circle animation non stop. I am pulling code from my public git repo. I have no idea how to debug this. Things worked great when the app was super basic, but after adding gps functions failed only on my device. App works fine in browser on local computer also works as expected in Ripple. Only tested on Android device. Thanks!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use [adb logcat](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/tools/logcat.html) to get the stack trace from the phone.  If you're lucky the stack trace will provide a clear answer.

Did you add GeoLocation permissions to the manifest when you added GPS to the application?  You'll need the `http://api.phonegap.com/1.0/geolocation` permission in `config.xml`?   https://build.phonegap.com/docs/config-xml

Comment: +1 this was really helpful. i was able to find the problem through using logcat. for some reason a jquery plugin is not being defined properly once the app gets into the apk version. works fine in the browser though, so i'm not sure why it'd work there and not from the github/phonegap service on the device...